# Simple google map using php

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

new to web development and was just wondering if there was an easy way of drawing simple latitude and longitude coordinates from a table and rendering them on a map. I have created a simple place page that uses php to draw the name, address etc from each stored place within a place table. I just want to create a really simple map that would display a marker at the lat and lng coordinates. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a PHP issue. It uses javascript.

This should do it:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    var myMap;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.518903284520796,-1.450427753967233);
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  ,
            scrollwheel: false
        }
        myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: myMap,
            title: 'Name Of Business',
            icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png'
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map" style="width:500px; height: 500px;">

</div>
```

Just Change the myLatLng Variable to what you want.

Here's the documentation if you need more help:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#HelloWorld

Comment: So do I set my php variables lat and lng as javascript variables?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just wondering what's the easiest way to set a php variable $lng and $lat as a javascript variable that I can call upon in the code you provided?

Comment: Just replace it with:
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat ?>,<?php echo $lng ?>);

Comment: Those variables must be set before hand through obviously

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. Here is the getting started part of the Google Maps API. You just need to sign up for a API key but it's all written in there.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: Why would you need an API key to use Google Maps? I didn't

Comment: If you want to use all the features of the google maps API and not just embed a map then you need it. See the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
<?php
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=West+Bridgford&sensor=false&region=UK";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($response, true);

//print_r($response);

$lat = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$long = $response['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

echo "latitude: " . $lat . " longitude: " . $long;
?>
```